# Saving Values in Application State - Should I lock also when reading

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Looking at this [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/94xkskdf(v=vs.100).aspx) that explains how to save values in application level, I understand that one should lock the application state using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application.Lock();` in order to prevent invalid data (cause it "can be accessed by multiple threads at the same time").

My question is - should I also lock the application state when reading? or is it enough to lock it only on writing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should.

When you have a shared resource, the lock keeps the object's integrity.
If you have only locks on the writes, there is a scenario where one thread is in the middle of writing something to the resource, and then another thread tries to read that same resource.

So because the read isn't locked it could either read data that is half-way cooked.
Or, if the resource is a collection, the whole integrity of the collection structure could be invalid while in the middle of inserting an item.

Farther more, loops on a collection will throw an exception as the collection iterators become invalidated because of the change that was made in the other thread.

Comment: This may be true for `decimal` and `double` but `int` and references are always read/written atomically. Still a good idea to just always lock.